# Im trying to create a dictionary of brands and then clean an input of a certain transaction to extract only the brand name

Tags: r, tm, string-substitution

Im working with gsub to erase every word after a brand in the dictionary, but how can I erase the words before to?
Hi, Im trying to clean transactions to look clearly at the brands that the clients use. This is an example using gsub and erasing every word after the brand "cabify"

```
tabla1_texto <- "exppcabify u.s.2313; 1212; 534"

tabla1_texto <- gsub("cabify", "cabify-", tabla1_texto)
tabla1_texto <- gsub(";", " ;",tabla1_texto)
tabla1_texto <- gsub("-\\S* ","", tabla1_texto)
```

this erase every character till the ";", how can I delete the "expp" to?

Someone also knows how can i create a dictionary of brands automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To delete the prior word, you can use:

`gsub("\\w+(?=cabify)", "", tabla1_texto, perl = TRUE`)

To delete everything before, you can use:

```
gsub(".*(?=cabify)", "", tabla1_texto, perl = TRUE)
```

A starting point for a "dictionary" could be:

```
brands <- c("cabify", "thundersausage")
  for (brand in brands) {
  tabla1_texto <- gsub(brand, paste0(brand, "-"), tabla1_texto)
  tabla1_texto <- gsub(";", " ;",tabla1_texto)
  tabla1_texto <- gsub("-\\S* ","", tabla1_texto)
  tabla1_texto <- gsub(paste0("\\w+(?=", brand, ")"), "", tabla1_texto, perl = TRUE)
  }
tabla1_texto # view the result
```